# Angular Routing Data

Tags: angular, routes

I have a small problem. I want to pass data from my products, to my single product page. So I have a products page with 10-15 products to display with title of the product, small description, picture and a button for more info. When I click on that button I want to be redirected to that product page. So it says localhost:4200/product/productTitle1 and its picture, description and title can be used on that page like {{ title }}.

So I have **products component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let product of productList.products" class="col-sm">
 <div class="card mt-5" style="width: 20rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title">{{ product.title }}</h4>
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{ product.subtitle }}</h6>
    <img [src]="product.imageUrl" class="card-text img-fluid">{{ product.cardText }}<br>
    <a [routerLink]="['/product', product.title]" class="card-link btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm mt-3">More info</a>
    <a href="#" class="card-link btn btn-info btn-sm mt-3">Add to cart</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

with **routerLink** that shows product title in the link and redirect me to his product info page

```
[routerLink]="['/product', product.title]
```

and here is **single product.component.ts**

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit{
  title: string;
  subtitle: string;
  cardText: string;

constructor(
  private productList: ProductService, 
  private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
  let params = this.route.snapshot.paramMap;
  this.title  = params.get('title');
  this.subtitle  = params.get('subtitle');
  this.cardText = params.get('cardText');
 }
}
```

and **product.service.ts** that contain all product informations.

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
  products: any[] = [
{
  id: 1,
  title: 'Some title',
  subtitle: 'Some subtitle',
  imageUrl: './assets/images/main-image.jpg',
  cardText: 'Some descriptive text'
},
{
  id: 2,
  title: 'Some title about second product',
  subtitle: 'Some subtitle 2',
  imageUrl: './assets/images/prod-cop.png',
  cardText: 'Some text'
}, ...
```

The thing is that I can't see any information about that product on single product page except the `{{ title }}`. But I noticed that if I type like this `routerLink =['/product', product]` I can access all the information with snapshot but the link will contain all the information as well, which looks bad.
I am still beginner in Angular so I need your help.

Answer (score 1):

As you already have a service you do not have to pass the data from route. just get the product id from route parameters and find the product from your product service

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit{
 product: any;

constructor(
  private productList: ProductService, 
  private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
  const productId = route.snapshot.params['productId'];
  this.product = this.prodcutList.products.find((product)=>{
   return product.id === productId
   });
 }
}
```

now generate the link

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/product']" [queryParams]="{productId: product.id}">More info</a>
```

your ProductComponent HTML template can now use the product object

Comment: Thanks for answer! But I am getting 2 syntax errors. Property 'find' does not exist on type 'ProductService' and product: Product.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo find is a function on array. fixed the answer

Comment: Yeap, the find() is fixed! But product: Product still gives an error. "Cannot find name 'Product'."

Comment: For some reason when I use {{ product.title }} at my template with your code it gives a error ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Comment: Thanks but it still gives me a "Cannot read property title of undefined". When I print "this.product" it also gives me undefined

Comment: can you check if you are getting the project id ? and see the list of projects ? the find function will return of the product is already available

Comment: Yes I am getting a product Id for every product like this `http://localhost:4200/product?productId=1` and I can see the list of products. But I can't still access their title, description... on the single product page of that product.

Comment: put a console.log(this.product) in the code at end of ngOnInit method and check whats logged please

Comment: It just writes `undefined` in console

Comment: can you also check what this line is showing console.log(this.prodcutList.products) again at the end of method

Comment: It gives me all the products `(7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]` and I can open each one with all it's information.

Comment: Just realized there is typo route.snapshot.params['productId'] I fixed it

Comment: Yea I saw that typo and fixed it before. There are still few typos, should be this.route and this.productList. But still can't get it to work.

Comment: I noticed that if I change in `[queryParams]="{productId: product.id}`, `product.id` to `product`, I get `http://localhost:4200/product?productId=%5Bobject%20Object%5D` . So maybe the problem is in objects. Maybe I should remove some [ ] so it doesn't get 2 objects. `product.title`, `product.subtitle` works, so it is getting the right information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass id in the url `[routerLink]="['/product', product.id]` and you add a new method on you service like `getProductById(id)` by calling it in your single product page

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the information shown in route, you can use skipLocationChange flag as below

```
this.router.navigateByUrl("/product/"+id,{skipLocationChange:true});
```